# Horizontal Recycler view with left and right arrow Indicators

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to implement a horizontal recycleview with right and left arrow indicators. So what happens is if one clicks the right arrow next item should appear and if one clicks the left arrow the previous item should appear and also at the end of the list the left arrow should disappear. I have no Idea how ti implement this. can someone help me out? Below is my Horizontal Recyclerview adapter.

```
public class DialogRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DialogRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

Context context;

List<UploadImage> dataAdapters;
private SharedPreferences.Editor mSharedPrefEditor;

ImageLoader imageLoader;

public DialogRecyclerViewAdapter(List<UploadImage> getDataAdapter, Context context){

    super();
    this.dataAdapters = getDataAdapter;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cardview, parent, false);

    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);

    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder Viewholder, int position) {

    final UploadImage dataAdapterOBJ =  dataAdapters.get(position);

    imageLoader = ImageAdapter.getInstance(context).getImageLoader();

    imageLoader.get(dataAdapterOBJ.getImage(),
            ImageLoader.getImageListener(
                    Viewholder.VollyImageView,//Server Image
                    R.drawable.loading_1,//Before loading server image the default showing image.
                    android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert //Error image if requested image dose not found on server.
            )
    );

    Viewholder.VollyImageView.setImageUrl(dataAdapterOBJ.getImage(), imageLoader);

    Viewholder.ImageTitleTextView.setText(dataAdapterOBJ.getBrand_name());

    Viewholder.garment_price.setText(dataAdapterOBJ.getGarment_price());


    Viewholder.VollyImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MihuChatApplication.getInstance().getContext());
            mSharedPrefEditor = sharedPref.edit();
            mSharedPrefEditor.putString(Constants.KEY_FROM_CHAT, "fromChatWIndow").apply();


            Intent i=new Intent(MihuChatApplication.getInstance().getContext(), DetailsNewActivity.class);
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

            //PACK DATA TO SEND
            i.putExtra("image_title",dataAdapterOBJ.getGarment_name());

            i.putExtra("image_url",dataAdapterOBJ.getImage_full());
            i.putExtra("desc_text", dataAdapterOBJ.getDesc_text());
            //i.putExtra("image_url2", imageLarger);

            i.putExtra("image_price", dataAdapterOBJ.getGarment_price());
            //i.putExtra("disc_price", disc_price);
            //open activity
            MihuChatApplication.getInstance().getApplicationContext().startActivity(i);
        }
    });

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {

    return dataAdapters.size();
}

class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    public TextView ImageTitleTextView, garment_price;
    public NetworkImageView VollyImageView ;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {

        super(itemView);

        garment_price = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.garment_price);

        ImageTitleTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ImageNameTextView) ;

        VollyImageView = (NetworkImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.VolleyImageView) ;

    }
}
```

}

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i worked it year ago, what i did was use two clickable images at ends and between them my recycler view and wrote the logic as you said to scroll the view left or right and at the end hide the buttons

Comment: Can you post some piece code of code so i can understand it better

Comment: currently i dont hav it will update if i got

Comment: Ok thanks in advance

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try the following

here img_LeftScroll is the left imageview and img_right_scroll is the right imageview between the horizontal list, rv_horizontal is the horizontallist view

then onclick of the image view do the below, hope it works

```
 img_LeftScroll.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (horizontalLayoutManagaer.findFirstVisibleItemPosition() > 0) {
                rv_horizontal.smoothScrollToPosition(horizontalLayoutManagaer.findFirstVisibleItemPosition() - 1);
            } else {
                rv_horizontal.smoothScrollToPosition(0);
            }

        }
    });

 img_right_scroll.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            rv_horizontal.smoothScrollToPosition(horizontalLayoutManagaer.findLastVisibleItemPosition() + 1);
        }
    });
```

Comment: can you tell me how to hide the right indicator at the end of the list?

Comment: you can hide the right image view by checking horizontalLayoutManagaer.findLastVisibleItemPosition is equal to your list size in the right image view click

Comment: https://github.com/RameshBhupathi/RecyclerViewWithLeftAndRightArrowsExample -- example

Comment: @AmruthaSaj its should be  layout_mangaer.findLastVisibleItemPosition() == modelList.size()-1 then we can hide the next arrow

Comment: @AmruthaSaj Thanks...To simple and short code....Its working like charm

Answer (score 5):

Horizontal Recycler view with left and right arrow Indicators --I have Done this By creating a custom Layout with recyclerVIew and two arrow images --

```
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
            switch (newState) {
                case SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING:
                    //Indicated that user scrolled.
                    programaticallyScrolled = false;
                    break;
                case SCROLL_STATE_IDLE:
                    if (!programaticallyScrolled) {
                        currentVisibleItem = linearLayoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
                        handleWritingViewNavigationArrows(false);
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
```

Hide/Show navigation arrows

```
 /**
 * Handles the arrows visibility based on current visible items and scrolls the
 * current visibility item based on param scroll.
 *
 * Scroll - is False if User scrolls the Reycler Manually
 *        - is True means User used arrows to navigate
 *
 * @param scroll
 */
private void handleWritingViewNavigationArrows(boolean scroll) {
    if (currentVisibleItem == (recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount() - 1)) {
        rightArrow.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        leftArrow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else if (currentVisibleItem != 0) {
        rightArrow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        leftArrow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else if (currentVisibleItem == 0) {
        leftArrow.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        rightArrow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    if (scroll) {
        recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(currentVisibleItem);
    }
}
```

> Check the example for the reference hope it helps u

https://github.com/RameshBhupathi/RecyclerViewWithLeftAndRightArrowsExample

Answer (score 0):

This code works in my case:

```
btn_to_right.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        p = linearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition() - 1;
        recyclerview.smoothScrollToPosition( p);
        checkVisibility();
    }
});


btn_to_left.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        p = linearLayoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition() + 1;
        recyclerview.smoothScrollToPosition(p);
        checkVisibility();
    }
});


public void checkVisibility() {
    if (p < 1) {
        btn_to_right.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        btn_to_left.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else if (p >= (recyclerview.getAdapter().getItemCount() - 1)) {
        btn_to_right.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        btn_to_left.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        btn_to_right.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        btn_to_left.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Much simpler approach for hiding/showing arrows:

```
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);


            if (manager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()==0){
                leftArrow.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }else{
                leftArrow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            if (manager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()==list.size()-1){
                rightArrow.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }else
                rightArrow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
        }
    });
```

Comment: The layout manager which is set for the recycler view. For example:   LinearLayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(this); mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);