# How to set horizontal scroll with show next and previous data in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

In my application i want use `recyclerView` for show special data, and for this i want use `recyclerview` with **horizontal** scroll with show **next** and **previous** data.
such as **banner** and below **image** : [enter link description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Y6IA.jpg)

How can i use `LayoutManager` for this?

For this, i know i should use **Horizontal** in `LinearLayout`. but i don't know how can i show next and previous data

Please don't give me negative points and please help me.

Comment: Why you can not try `ViewPager`

Comment: @Sniffer, i want use RecyclerView. can you help me for this?

Comment: [next/previous arrow indicator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47864621/horizontal-recycler-view-with-left-and-right-arrow-indicators?rq=1) please follow this link it work for me.

Comment: @dhananjaysingh, thanks dear but i don't want show next and previous arrow . i want partial next and previous data

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming you need to only show one full item at a time and 2 partial items at both the sides. You can use `snaphelper` to snap recylerview to nearest item position for having the desired effect. And change the width of your item inside the recycler view in the following way. You need to pass the `recyclerView` reference inside your adapter to get the width.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
    final SnapHelper snapHelper = new PagerSnapHelper();
    snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
}
```

and in your `onCreateViewHolder` change the width of your item.

```
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int i) {
    final View view =
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.your_view, parent, false);
    // recyclerView is your passed view.
    int width = recyclerView.getWidth();
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = view.getLayoutParams();
    params.width = (int)(width * 0.8);
    view.setLayoutParams(params);
    return new YourViewHolder(view);
}
```

Comment: yes dear i know i should use Horizontal in LinearLayout. but i don't know how can i show next and previous data

Comment: do you mean, you want to show the partial next and previous data?

Comment: Yes my friend. such as above image . can you help me?

Comment: Are you here dear? can you help me?

Comment: thanks dear, u use int width = recyclerView.getWidth(); code. for use recyclerview i should pass my recyclerview from activity to adapter?

Comment: yes yes , it's work me. thaaaaaaanks my dear friend, thanks <3

Comment: Happy to help :)

Comment: sorry i can't upvote you. because my points is 8 and for this my points should up 15

Comment: This seems to work for what @DJAl has to implement.
I wish to just show the next, not the previous. Can this be manipulated to work for that too? like this - https://medium.com/deliveroo-design/framer-x-deliveroo-the-veteran-challenge-e4f3bf6c4d5e